# проблема с отображением картинки в лейбле tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
rom tkinter import *

#создание окна
root = Tk()
root.title("D&D prog")
root.geometry("976x557")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

canvas = Canvas(root, width =976, height=557)

stwin = PhotoImage(file="resurses\start.gif")
start = Label(root, image=stwin)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

этот код должен выводить на всё окно картинку, но этого не происходит. Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, слэши нужно экранировать

```
stwin = PhotoImage(file="resurses\\start.gif")
```

Во-вторых, label надо отобразить

```
start.pack()
```

Наконец, для отображения картинки в label не нужен canvas.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)